# How to declare NUMERIC filed in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have entity:

```
data class DropsDeposit(
    val userId: Int,
    val articleId: Int,
    val quantity: BigDecimal
)
```

My problem is with `quantity` field type. I was using double type, but in that case, I had problems with conversions to floating-point numbers.
So, a have used BigDecimal and my problem disappeared.

Unfortunately now is another problem. When I try to get the value I get only 6 digits.
I have also type converter for custom conversions from String to BigDecimal

```
class BigDecimalTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toBigDecimal(number: String): BigDecimal {
        Timber.e("BigDecimalTypeConverter numberStr: $number")
        return BigDecimal(number, MathContext.UNLIMITED)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromBigDecimal(number: BigDecimal): String {
        return number.toPlainString()
    }
}
```

e.g.

When column quantity has `444.1234567` value, the corresponding value in object value is `444.123`

When column quantity has `0.0004567` value, the corresponding value in object value is `0.0004567`

Logs from Timber shows me that values got from the database are wrong (exactly like in sample above)

I wanted to setup affinity for field to NUMERIC
`@ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.NUMERIC)`
But this affinity type is not available.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: what is the max size for quantity?

Comment: @Karol may be due to you are using toPlainString() in your type converter how about if you use just toString()?

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda The problem is read from db not conversion. `number` is wrong

Comment: @Eishon It's not defined but I assume it is about 10000. But more important is to keep correct conversions, so double/float aren't proper solution

Comment: The quantity describes dose of medicines in hospital, and to is a fraction quite often

Comment: @Karol  https://android--code.blogspot.com/2019/07/android-kotlin-room-typeconverter.html

Comment: @Karol then use double as you have fractional units. I think it's enough to cover your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big your quantity is, but if it is between the following range, you can use ULong (Range: 0 to 2^64 -1).

[image]

[More info](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#unsigned-integers) on basic types.

**Update**

Use Double for in case you have tomaintain fractional inputs. It also has the range same as Long.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to setup affinity for field to NUMERIC @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.NUMERIC) But this affinity type is not available.

That is because Room doesn't support NUMERIC and it's not going to resolve the issues. NUMERIC is a catch all type affinity. The affinity best suited is REAL which Float or Double would use. Although when it boils down to it the affinity doesn't really come into play as SQLite can store any type in any column, what matters is the SQL generated when inserting the data, over which you have little control.

Consider the following based upon a slightly modified DropsDeposit Entity :-

```
@Entity
data class DropsDeposit(
    @PrimaryKey
    val userId: Int? = null,
    val articleId: Int = 0,
    val quantity: Double,
    val quantity2: Float
)
```

- To demonstrate Float and Double (which is what you would have to ultimately store the data as)

  - Another option would be to store the value as a string using a non-numeric character to prevent SQLite storing it as a numeric value e.g. `#4444.123456789`.

Standard insert and extract Dao's exists (and for rerunabillity a delete all Dao).

using the following code :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDao()
    dao.deleteAllDropsDeposit()
    val dec = DecimalFormat("#.0000000000")
    var q: Double = 4444.123456789;
    var q2: Float = 4444.123456789F;
    Log.d("DDINFO","q = ${q}  q2 = ${q2} qf = ${dec.format(q)} qf2 = ${dec.format(q2)}")
    dao.insert(DropsDeposit(quantity = q /*DOUBLE*/,quantity2 = q2 /*FLOAT*/))
    for (d: DropsDeposit in dao.getAllDropsDeposit()) {
        Log.d("DDINFO","q = ${d.quantity}  q2 = ${d.quantity2} qf = ${dec.format(d.quantity)} qf2 = ${dec.format(d.quantity2)}")
    }
```

Then :-

The database (via Android Studio's Database Inspector) shows :-

[image]

That is the data is being stored in the database with greater precision than what you are experiencing (NUMERIC wouldn't change this). However, you will noting that the Float's (quantity2) precision is only to 4dp and that the 4th has been rounded up from 4 to 5. I'd suggest not by SQLite but because of Float.

Now the output to the log:-

The first line is before any data has been inserted and is the values being stored. Showing that the issue you are facing exists prior to storing the data.

```
D/DDINFO: q = 4444.123456789  q2 = 4444.1235 qf = 4444.1234567890 qf2 = 4444.1235351562
```

true to how the data was stored the output via the extracted data is identical

```
D/DDINFO: q = 4444.123456789  q2 = 4444.1235 qf = 4444.1234567890 qf2 = 4444.1235351562
```

- q, Double, printed without formatting is fine.
- q2, Float, printed without formatting is to 4 dp and rounded.
- qf, Formatted Double, is fine other than the additional trailing 0 to satisfy the precision of the format
- qf2, Formatted Float, printed with formatting according to the data.

If the code is amended to add the following immediately before the loop :-

```
    q = q + 0.000000000001  - q + 0.9
    q2 = q2 +  0.00001f - q2 + 0.9f
    Log.d("DDINFO","q = ${q}  q2 = ${q2} qf = ${dec.format(q)} qf2 = ${dec.format(q2)}")
    dao.insert(DropsDeposit(quantity = q /*DOUBLE*/,quantity2 = q2 /*FLOAT*/))
```

Then the output to the log before the insert is :-

```
D/DDINFO: q = 0.9000000000009095  q2 = 0.9 qf = .9000000000 qf2 = .8999999762
```

The database :-

[image]

The output after extracting is identical to before.

As such your issue is not with how the data is stored in the database but rather with the types. I.e. the limitations of Float.